# MongoDB Serialization() is not supported

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

Not sure what I am doing and can not find any other references out there about what this error is or even related to.

I get the error message `Serialization().Reference is not supported` when I try the code below with MondoDB and C#.NET.

I first tried this in my code:

```
var maxReference = await Events.Find(p => true)
                               .SortByDescending(p => p.Reference)
                               .Project(p => p.Reference)
                               .FirstOrDefault();
```

When that failed on the `FirstOrDefault` method, I slowly removed method by method until I had to do this:

```
var list = await Events.Find(p => true).ToListAsync();
var maxReference = list.Select(p => p.Reference)
                       .OrderByDescending(p => p)
                       .FirstOrDefault();
```

I was willing to work with this if it was a real limitation, but I ran into it again when I tried to use the `ReplaceOneAsync` method.

```
var form = new Event { Reference = maxReference + 1 };
var options = new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true };

await Events.ReplaceOneAsync(p => p.Reference == maxReference, form, options);
```

My POCO is defined as:

```
[BsonIgnoreExtraElements]
public class Event : IEvent
{
    public Event() {}

    public Event(int reference)
    {
        Reference = reference;
    }

    [BsonId]
    public ObjectId EventID { get; set; }

    [BsonRequired]
    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    public int Reference { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: have you tried removing the BsonRequired?

Comment: i am stuck on the same problem. did you find any solution?

Comment: I did finally find an answer. I have posted an answer. Not sure if this is what you experienced, but my issue had to do with Nancy and Dependency Injection. I found I could not use interfaces the way I thought or had with other DI systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turned out to be in my case that in dependency injection I used interfaces and that is not supported. I guess it has to do with instantiation of the Mongo Documents? Below is the final bootstrapper class. So it appears to ended up as not a Mongo problem as much as a Nancy problem.

I change the line
`var collection = database.GetCollection<ICollection>("collection");`
to
`var collection = database.GetCollection<Collection>("collection");`.

Notice the ICollection interface to Collection class. And everything worked after that.

Before:

```
public class Bootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(TinyIoCContainer container)
    {
        var connectionString = ;
        var databaseName = ;

        var client = new MongoClient("MongoDatabaseURL");
        container.Register(client);

        var database = client.GetDatabase("MongoDatabaseName");
        container.Register(database);

        var collection = database.GetCollection<ICollection>("collection");
        container.Register(collection);
    }
}
```

After:

```
public class Bootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper {
    protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(TinyIoCContainer container)
    {
        var connectionString = ;
        var databaseName = ;

        var client = new MongoClient("MongoDatabaseURL");
        container.Register(client);

        var database = client.GetDatabase("MongoDatabaseName");
        container.Register(database);

        var collection = database.GetCollection<Collection>("collection");
        container.Register(collection);
    }
}
```